# cant get sticky navbar to stick

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Im trying to get the navbar to stick on scroll I ve applied what ive found on w3schools and looked at a few posts here Im not getting it to work though. My codepen is:
https://codepen.io/robot_head/full/qKQwqe/

my code is as follows

html:

```
  <header class="header-logo">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">client</a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="#info">Info</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="header-img">
        <img src="img/logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
      </div>
    </header>
```

css:

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the navbar
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: yes bootstrap-4

Comment: Read the Sticky Top section https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/compaonents/navbar/.

Comment: Why not just add fixed-top bootstrap class to your nav component?

Comment: Also you are using getElementById to find an id that doesn't match any element in your html.

Comment: id navbar is missing in HTML https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MXzNvq it works

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Bootstrap 3, you can avoid using JS for the sticky navbar. In particular, note that I added the class navbar-fixed-top to the header. Here's the working code:

```css
.header-logo {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #06529d;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}


/* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #06529d;
}


/*about us */

#about {
  background-color: #06529d;
  height: 600px;
  color: #fff;
}

#lion-img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/*contact us */

#contact {
  background-color: #febb2e;
  height: 500px;
  color: #000;
}

.form-area {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  padding: 10px 40px 60px;
  margin: 10px 0px 60px;
  border: 1px solid GREY;
}

.control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

button#submit {
  background-color: #8d1f2d;
  border-color: #8d1f2d;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* Add a gray background color and some padding to the footer */

footer {
  background-color: #06529d;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 25px;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<header class="header-logo">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Site</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#info">Info</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="header-img">
    <img src="img/logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
  </div>
</header>
<div>
  <div class="container text-center">
    <img src="img/ceylon-hero.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center" id="about">
  <h3>ABOUT US</h3>
  <br>
  <div class="container text-center" id="lion-cage">
    <img src="img/lion.png" class="img-responsive" id="lion-img" alt="Image">
  </div>
  <div class="container about-text">
    <p>Hands long clothes execution dock careen lass overhaul code of conduct jib chandler broadside scuttle grog boom port salmagundi coffer Jack Tar mizzen gibbet come about. Wherry Davy Jones' Locker tack sutler Cat o'nine tails lanyard barkadeer jury
      mast hail-shot spyglass plunder broadside port sloop galleon Pirate Round furl careen bilge rat weigh anchor. Arr keel schooner Jack Tar Blimey cackle fruit spirits trysail sheet loaded to the gunwalls lugger Cat o'nine tails line gibbet Pirate
      Round cable bilge water chantey swing the lead Privateer.</p>
    <br>
    <p>Lugger bilge deadlights ye spirits wench bilged on her anchor bring a spring upon her cable Plate Fleet killick dead men tell no tales me Jack Tar Cat o'nine tails Corsair coxswain nipper fire ship yard ahoy. Log mizzen line ho tack blow the man down
      heave down yard hulk crack Jennys tea cup fluke schooner main sheet sheet fathom dance the hempen jig Blimey hands cable hearties. Blow the man down lanyard Plate Fleet grog blossom Sink me wherry come about ho American Main Arr brigantine overhaul
      gabion ahoy hornswaggle nipperkin log Sea Legs keelhaul Blimey.</p>
    <br>
    <p>Me run a rig Buccaneer swing the lead Sink me hardtack capstan smartly tender Brethren of the Coast scuppers brig jib Barbary Coast belaying pin belay careen coffer matey Spanish Main. Transom dead men tell no tales lookout hempen halter grapple square-rigged
      Spanish Main handsomely fore loot shrouds bring a spring upon her cable red ensign man-of-war avast cable fathom grog keelhaul jack. Cackle fruit jack wherry chandler cutlass Buccaneer grog blossom crack Jennys tea cup warp bilge rat haul wind sheet
      bilge water Jack Ketch matey chase red ensign deadlights execution dock gaff.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center" id="contact">
  <h3>CONTACT US</h3>
  <br>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-push-2">
      <form role="form">
        <br style="clear:both">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="control" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SEND</button>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer class="container-fluid text-center" id="info">
  <p>Footer Text</p>
</footer>
```

Notice that if you were to use Bootstrap 4, the class that you would have to add is either `sticky-top` or `fixed-top`.

The reason why your JS isn't working is that you're getting the navbar by ID, when navbar is actually a class. A quick fix to keep using your JS, is to add the ID navbar, like so:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="navbar">
```

Your edited codepen looks like this: https://codepen.io/robot_head/pen/qKQwqe